# Почему в intent записываются нули?

Tags: java, android

Есть сервис, в котором происходит получение координат через `LocationManager`, запись их в БД SQLite. Пытаюсь передать координаты в `MainActivity`, чтобы поместить их на карту в виде маркера.

Для передачи использую `Intent`, а в `MainActivity` `BroadcastReceiver`, который собственно и принимает значения координат. Но почему-то в сервисе в `Intent` записываются нули, а не значения широты и долготы.

По логу смотрел, в методе `getLocation()` значения широты и долготы реальные(не нули).

Вот примерный код сервиса:

```
public class TrackerService extends Service implements LocationListener {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
LocationManager locationManager;
double latitude, longitude;
LatLng myPosition;
Calendar addTimeCalendar;
String addDate;
Cursor c = null;
Location location;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000 * 60, 25, this);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "GPS_Provider request location updates");
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60, 25, this);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Network_Provider request location updates");
    getLocation(location);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "before run");
    run();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void run() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "run");
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
    intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "lat = " + latitude + " lng = " + longitude);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    //stop();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    getLocation(location);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    getLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

public void getLocation(Location location) {
            if (location == null)
                return;
            if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "GPS Provider Enabled");
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                myPosition = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "______in getLocation______");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "GPS lat = " + latitude + " GPS lng = " + longitude);
                addCoordinates();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "---GPS Координаты добавлены---");
            } else if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "NETWORK PROVIDER Enabled");
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                myPosition = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "______in getLocation______");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "WIFI lat = " + latitude + " WIFI lng = " + longitude);
                addCoordinates();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "---Network Координаты добавлены---");
            }
}

public void addCoordinates() {
    addTimeCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat addDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    addDate = addDayFormat.format(addTimeCalendar.getTime());
    SQL sqlHelper = new SQL(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in coordinates: ---");
    cv.put("Latitude", latitude);
    cv.put("Longitude", longitude);
    cv.put("Time", addDate);
    long rowID = db.insert("coordinates", null, cv);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
    db.close();
    sqlHelper.close();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopSelf();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
}
```

Comment: а из интента, что вытаскиваешь double или int ?

Comment: @aratj, и latitude и longitude типа double

Comment: я про то, что из даты интента, можно брать не то, я просто сам бывало "пихал" long , забирал getInt , потом голову ломал , что же не так.

Comment: @aratj, с этим вопросов нет, забираю через getDouble

Answer (score 2):

если в дебаге при отправке интента данные корректные, то ошибка скорее всего в том, что ты их не корректно достаешь. запости код получения из интента данных

Comment: почему-то данные из getLocation() не попадают run()

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего первый вызов `getLocation()` из `onStartCommand()` возвращает нули. Корректные данные приходят из `onLocationChanged();`

Вы должны отправить данные только после этого метода. Также проверить, что они действительно обновлены, т.к. не всегда удаётся быстро получить координаты.